# What's the cache_ok flag in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the next custom type decorator for **SQLAlchemy**:

```
class TimeStamp(TypeDecorator):
    impl = DateTime
    cache_ok = True
    LOCAL_TIMEZONE = datetime.utcnow().astimezone().tzinfo

    def process_literal_param(self, value, dialect):
        return self.imple.process_literal_param(value, dialect)

    @property
    def python_type(self):
        return self.impl.python_type

    def process_bind_param(self, value: datetime, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if value.tzinfo is None:
            value = value.astimezone(self.LOCAL_TIMEZONE)
        return value.astimezone(timezone.utc)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if value.tzinfo is None:
            return value.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
        return value.astimezone(timezone.utc)
```

The problem is that **SQLAlchemy** asks me to setup the `cache_ok` flag... I've tried to read about this flag in [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator.cache_ok) but it's still not clear for me. I can't get how **SQLAlchemy** uses it.
**What does it cache? Is my type decorator suitable for caching?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran into this recently, found your question, no answer :( .. looked further, looked into the docs ..

> The TypeDecorator.cache_ok class-level flag indicates if this custom TypeDecorator is safe to be used as part of a cache key. This flag defaults to None which will initially generate a warning when the SQL compiler attempts to generate a cache key for a statement that uses this type. If the TypeDecorator is not guaranteed to produce the same bind/result behavior and SQL generation every time, this flag should be set to False; otherwise if the class produces the same behavior each time, it may be set to True. See TypeDecorator.cache_ok for further notes on how this works.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator

.. so if you're confident that your TypeDecorator always produces the same bind/result for a given value then go ahead and issue that statement by setting the value `cache_ok = True` in your TypeDecorator class.

Comment: Thank you! However what’s a cache key? To be honest I don’t understand even what this flag is for

Comment: As I understand it it's related to caching practices in databases that SQLAlchemy supports, like PostgreSQL for example, though I eagerly admit I haven't looked deeply into those caching practices.